# How to make agenda view show tasks deadlined tomorrow or another number of days ahead?

Tags: org-mode

I want to make my org agenda view to show separate blocks for tasks deadlined for today, for tomorrow, and for a sertain number of days ahead. I have tried the following code:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(
("d" "deadlined tasks"(      
    (tags-todo "+TODO={NEXT}+DEADLINE>=\"<Today>\" "  (
        (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(scheduled-down))
        (org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadline today")
        ))
    (tags-todo "+TODO={NEXT}+DEADLINE>=\"<Today>\"+1 "  (
        (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(scheduled-down))
        (org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadline tomorrow")
        ))
    (tags-todo "+TODO={NEXT}+DEADLINE>=\"<Today>\"+2 "  (
        (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(scheduled-down))
        (org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadline in two days")
        ))
```

))

What is wrong in my code? How can I filter out tasks deadlined for n number of days ahead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [org-super-agenda](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda).

With org-super-agenda, you just need to set:

```
(let ((org-super-agenda-groups
       '(;; Each group has an implicit boolean OR operator between its selectors.
         (:name "Deadline Future"
                :deadline future)))))
```

For more usages of `org-super-ageda`, you can check the [examples](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda/blob/master/examples.org).

> :deadline
>
> Group items that have a deadline. Argument can be t (to match items with any deadline), nil (to match items that have no deadline), past (to match items with a deadline in the past), today (to match items whose deadline is today), or future (to match items with a deadline in the future). Argument may also be given like before DATE or after DATE where DATE is a date string that org-time-string-to-absolute can process.